# I am trying to implement lodash _.difference(array, [values]) using .filter() method

Tags: lodash

The method/function needs to return an array that has elements in the 1st array that are not present in the second array.

like,

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [2,3,4,5,6];
```

should return [1];
 and I need to do this using .filter() method!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.filter()` with `Array.includes()`:

```js
const arr1 = [1,2,3];
const arr2 = [2,3,4,5,6];

const difference = (a, b) => a.filter(item => !b.includes(item));
  
const result = difference(arr1, arr2);

console.log(result);
```